# Calculate Zipf-Mandelbrot parameters from distribution

Tags: distributions, estimation, power-law, zipf

I am fetching trending topics from social media where the frequency of likes is said to follow a Zipf-Mandelbrot distribution; i.e., some of the posts will have a high number of likes and some other very few.

So far I collected about 100 thousand samples and I want to calculate the `s` and `q` parameters. I looked at the script described [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRv0O.png). I ran the code on my data and it gives me the `s` parameter of `s=0.043`.

How do I calculate `q`?

The first figure is from the Python [Powerlaw package.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUQqQ.png)
[image: Fit curves]

[image: s-parameter]

[image: frequency]

PS: I'm a statistics newbie

---

The script in the answer generated the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In nlm(function(p) negloglik(p, x = x), p = c(20, 20)) :
  NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value
2: In nlm(function(p) negloglik(p, x = x), p = c(20, 20)) :
  NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value
3: In nlm(function(p) negloglik(p, x = x), p = c(20, 20)) :
  NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value
```

and this plot:

[image]

I modified the above script to fit my data:

```
> N <- 40480    # the size of my dataset
> x <- read.csv("dataset.txt")    # my dataset file
> negloglik <- function(parms, x=x) {
+     H <- sum(1/(1:N + parms[1])^parms[2])
+     -sum(log(1/(x + parms[1])^parms[2]/H))
+ }
> plot(d <- sapply(1:N, function(x) exp(-negloglik(c(5,5), x))))  # here I changed 10 to N (the size of my data)
> x <- sample(1:N, 1000, replace = T, prob = d)
> ml <- nlm(function(p) negloglik(p, x=x), p=c(20,20))
```

This output the following graph: (xy log scale)

[image]

However, I got a similar warning message:

```
Warning message:
In nlm(function(p) negloglik(p, x = x), p = c(20, 20)) :
  NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value
```

Comment: Just use maximum likelihood. I don't use Python, but there must be an optimizer, if not just build your own grid search. The density is a very simple one to implement.

Comment: @AdamO Do you use R? I'm trying to perform the MLE in R. The package PoweRlaw seems to do the job

Comment: As a semi-serious R programmer, I think learning how to fit general distributions is a great skill. I have an example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum likelihood can be done. I'm a little surprised by how badly the ML estimates converge. Example R code is shown below for calculating the density and negative log likelihood based on the parametrization in the Wikipedia page:

$$f_x(x) = \left( \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{(i + p)^s} \right)^{-1} \frac{1}{(x + p)^s}$$

```
set.seed(123)

## set a N = 10
N <- 10

## populate the negative log likelihood function
negloglik <- function(parms, x=x) {
  H <- sum(1/(1:N + parms[1])^parms[2])
  -sum(log(1/(x + parms[1])^parms[2]/H))
}

## generate pmf for sampling
plot(d <- sapply(1:10, function(x) exp(-negloglik(c(5,5), x))))

## draw a random sample with n=1000
x <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace = T, prob = d)

## calculate ml estimates
ml <- nlm(function(p) negloglik(p, x=x), p=c(20,20))
```